# Anyone know why Costco / Target pulled 'Just Mayo'?

Tags: dairy-substitutes

I was so happy to buy 'Just Mayo' at Costco but it doesn't appear to be there anymore.

Comment: Hello. I think your question would be best answered by asking Costco/Target directly as unless we have some Costco/Target high executive in our ranks, all answers will be just speculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from an article on VegNews from August of last year, and might answer your question, or at least give you a place to start looking for answers:

> On Friday, retailer Target informed Hampton Creek—makers of popular
>   vegan condiment Just Mayo—that it would end its contract with the food
>   technology company. On June 22, Target inexplicably removed all of the
>   company’s 20 products from retail and online outlets after receiving a
>   fraudulent letter that claimed, among other falsehoods, that Hampton
>   Creek products could be contaminated with listeria and/or salmonella.
>   At least one other retailer of Hampton Creek products received a
>   similar letter, and, instead of removing products from shelves,
>   contacted Hampton Creek directly to settle the issue. Last week,
>   Hampton Creek announced that the Food and Drug Administration (FDA)
>   had cleared the company’s products of any potential health threats and
>   revealed that its retail team had begun negotiations to be reinstated
>   at Target. “To our surprise, Target informed us that sharing with the
>   public the FDA’s conclusion that our products are safe somehow
>   violated Target’s vendor communication guidelines,” Hampton Creek CEO
>   Josh Tetrick said in a statement, wherein he also mentioned that the
>   company’s vegan cookie dough was the best-seller (outselling
>   similiarly positioned brands that contain animal products) at one
>   major retailer prior to Target pulling its products. Tetrick told
>   VegNews that the company will not pursue further action to reinstate
>   its products at Target and that Hampton Creek will move forward in its
>   pursuit to replace animal agriculture with plant-based foods, adding
>   that the loss of Target’s distribution points will not pose a
>   substantial financial threat to the company.